# bash output to json format

Tags: json, linux, bash

I'm new to Linux and Bash scripting.  I am trying to output several bash scripts in Ubuntu Linux into JSON format, however, I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

My goal is to get this:

```
date -u +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S  //date and time

lsb_release -a  //os distro version

ifconfig -a  //ip info
```

Into this format in JSON:

```
  "datetime":datetime_string,

  "osversion":string,

  "ip_info:  [{"interface":string,"ip_addr":string,"mask":string,"gateway":string},
             {"interface":string,"ip_addr":string,"mask":string,"gateway":string}],
```

Comment: jq -- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ -- is your friend.

Comment: Also, don't use `ifconfig`; it's an ancient tool nobody has maintained in over a decade. If you want to list IPs on Linux in a way that works with new and modern parts of the network stack, use `ip -o addr list`.

Comment: ...btw, `gateway` isn't present in the output of `ifconfig -a`. Since the routing table isn't interface-specific, one wouldn't really expect them to be stored/managed together...

Comment: Charles, how can I output that format without having to install additional packages on the distro?  I am trying to avoid having to install additional packages as much as possible.

Comment: Using a language with a built-in JSON module -- such as Python -- is your best bet, then.

Answer (score 3):

Bash itself has no JSON support. Thus, to guarantee conformance, you need to use an external utility with JSON parsing and generation support built in. [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is one of these, and the below uses its built-in regex support:

```
jq --raw-input \
   --arg date "$(date)" \
   --arg osver "$(lsb_release -a)" \
   '{"date": $date,
     "osver": $osver,
     "ip_info": [inputs |
                 capture("^[0-9]+: (?<ifname>[^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+inet (?<addr>[^[:space:]/]+)(/(?<masklen>[[:digit:]]+))?")
                ]
    }' \
   < <(ip -o addr list | grep 'inet ')
```

See this code in action [on JQPlay](https://jqplay.org/jq?j=%221%3A%20lo%20%20%20%20inet%20127.0.0.1/8%20scope%20host%20lo%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20valid_lft%20forever%20preferred_lft%20forever%22%0A%223%3A%20brProv%20%20%20%20inet%20192.168.1.2/24%20brd%20192.168.1.255%20scope%20global%20brProv%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20valid_lft%20forever%20preferred_lft%20forever%22%0A%224%3A%20br0%20%20%20%20inet%20192.168.119.128/24%20brd%20192.168.119.255%20scope%20global%20br0%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20valid_lft%20forever%20preferred_lft%20forever%22&q=%7B%22ip_info%22%3A%20%5Binputs%20%7C%20capture%28%22%5E%5B0-9%5D%2B%3A%20%28%3F%3Cifname%3E%5B%5E%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D%5D%2B%29%5B%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D%5D%2Binet%20%28%3F%3Caddr%3E%5B%5E%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D/%5D%2B%29%28/%28%3F%3Cmasklen%3E%5B%5B%3Adigit%3A%5D%5D%2B%29%29%3F%22%29%5D%7D).

---

If you can't install tools not built into your Linux distro, consider Python:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - important, not /bin/sh; this uses some bash-only syntax

py_code=$(cat <<'EOF'
import json, re, sys

content={'ip_info': []}
for k, v in [ arg.split('=', 1) for arg in sys.argv[2:] if '=' in arg ]:
  content[k]=v

ip_re = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+:\s+(?P<ifname>\S+)\s+inet (?P<addr>[^/\s]+)(?:/(?P<masklen>\d+))?')
for line in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines():
  m = ip_re.match(line)
  if not m: raise "NOOOO"
  content['ip_info'].append({
    'ifname': m.groups('ifname'),
    'addr': m.groups('addr'),
    'masklen': m.groups('masklen'),
  })

print json.dumps(content)
EOF
)

python -c "$py_code" \
  <(ip -o addr list | grep 'inet ') \
  "date=$(date)" "osver=$(lsb_release -a)"
```

Comment: Charles, how do I write this in Python 2.6.5 without jq?

Comment: @Fadiddy, see the extended/amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should be quite easy to do with [jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo):

```
jo datetime=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S) osversion=$(lsb_release -a) ip_info=$(jo -a $(ip -o addr list))
```

Comment: How does `jo` parse `ip -o addr list` into fields here? I don't see how it could get the desired output format.

Comment: Also, you need more quotes to prevent the shell from string-splitting your key/value pairs before they're passed to `jo`.